NPOI Column Stacked Chart?
I need to create a column chart on excel. I tried using NPOI for this.
var chart = (XSSFChart)drawing.CreateChart(anchor);
var chartData = chart.ChartDataFactory.CreateColumnChartData<string, double>();

But I can't seem to find any properties / options that can change this column chart into a stacked one?
